# Joining not included in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, datatables, nested

I´d like to ask you for help.
I have two tables. In tab1 one I have client_num and then personal data. And I wanna join tab1 with tab2, where are client_nums too but one client number can be on more rows. The second column in this tab2 is products written as numbers 1-5.

tab1
client_num; gender

```
1; M
2; F
3; F
4; M
```

tab2
client_num; product

```
1; 2
1; 3
1; 4
2; 1
2; 2
2; 3
3; 4
3; 1
```

And now I want just the clients who DON´T HAVE a product number 4

Could you help me with that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from clients c
where not exists (select 1
                  from client_products cp
                  where cp.client_num = c.client_num and
                        cp.product = 4
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:`SELECT tab1.* FROM tab1 WHERE tab1.client_num NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT tab2.client_num FROM tab2 WHERE tab2.product = 4);`

Please note that this will also output records of clients that do not have any entries in tab2. i.e. it will output 2 and 4 in the sample data provided by you.

If you intend to just list clients that have products associated in tab2, you can use this query:`SELECT DISTINCT tab1.* FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 USING(client_num) WHERE tab1.client_num NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT tab2.client_num FROM tab2 WHERE tab2.product = 4);`

The second query will output just 2, as per the sample data.